# Add increment column in VisiData

Tags: visidata

In VisiData `1.5.2`, how can I add a new column which contains the row number?

This can be done in version `2.0` by pressing `i` I think, but that does not work in `1.5.2`. When I try that it says:

`no command for "i"`

Maybe there's a way of referencing the current row number in a expression?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is more complicated than `i`, but it will work!

Use `za` to create a new column. Then move your cursor to that column, and press `gs`, then `gz=`. Type in *range(n)* where `n` is the number of rows in your sheet (you can reference the number in the buttom right corner).

Another option is that you can try putting the code for `i` (https://github.com/saulpw/visidata/blob/e2bbb7f60e069297f5da86f1cbe6faf3f606f72e/visidata/incr.py) in your installation of VisiData, and see if it 'just' works. VisiData's code was intentionally made very modular to allow for easier plug and play possibilities. Just make sure to add it to your imports in the `__init__` file as well: https://github.com/saulpw/visidata/blob/2cb5379f413dc9d7f0baae3e4f351bb7268efb32/visidata/__init__.py#L101

Comment: But also, consider upgrading your version. =) There is a lot of fun stuff that has been added since 1.5.2.

Comment: Thanks, the range(n) method works. Tried adding the code for i but no luck there, I'm sure it's possible but range is good enough for now.